# K8s Can share Persistent volume/Storage on different regions?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-storage

I have some questions about the K8s persistent volume that how to share the storage in a different region.

For example, I have two K8s clusters that have deployed to two different regions one cluster in East Asia another one in Southeast Asia.

These K8s clusters have the same deployment and configuration.

Any way can share the persistent storage in a different region or two clusters can mount the same persistent volume on the cloud platform?

Comment: Depends on cloud provider. Yes on Azure.

Comment: Could you share more details? Which cloud service on Azure?

Comment: Azure Files. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv).

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, but the document no mention the azure file support different region and cluster use same storage. Did you have experience with different K8s clusters using Azure File as Persistent Volume?

Comment: Azure Files is mounted as SMB file share on the nodes. It shouldn't matter which region the cluster is in (much the same way any VM in any region can mount the file share).

Comment: Hi mmking, I have been tested using Azure File for K8S cluster that can work cross-region, but I found the problem on the Azure file that can't sync data between region a cluster and region b cluster. Also, I need to configure the replica set for the refresh and sync data. Did you have any suggestions for sync data for different regions??

Comment: 1. Not sure what you mean by "can't sync data". Are you referring to files within a pod (which is what persistent volumes are for)? 2. Since this is outside the scope of the original question, I'd suggest asking a new question and updating with new details (what you've tried, what didn't work, etc).